# GWT SuperDevMode fails to see changes

Tags: java, maven, gwt, intellij-idea

I'm trying to setup my project to use gwt maven plugin. Its compiling properly but I'm not able to use either the dev mode or super dev mode for development.

My settings are as follows:

Maven configurations in order

```
mvn clean install
mvn tomcat7:run-war-only
mvn gwt:run-codeserver
```

GWT Version: `2.6.1`

IDE: `Intellij 14 Community Edition`

When I make changes to client java files and click the "compile" button on the code server page, they're not reflected on the webpage. I suspect the code server is not looking at  the same sources I'm changing. Specifically i think its looking for sources to compile in target/{project-name}/*

Following is the snippet of the POM file I'm using.

```
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>



    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <!--compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>${tomcat.context}</path>
                <port>${tomcat.webport}</port>
                <ajpPort>${tomcat.ajpport}</ajpPort>
                <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.gwt.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
                <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                <noServer>true</noServer>
                <port>${tomcat.webport}</port>
                <runTarget>${tomcat.context}/index.html</runTarget>
                <!--codeServerWorkDir>${webappDirectory}</codeServerWorkDir-->
                <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>${webappDirectory}</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>



    </plugins>

</build>
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: can you show your projectname.gwt.xml. Do you have the configuration below in your module xml?
<add-linker name="xsiframe" />
<set-configuration-property name="devModeRedirectEnabled" value="true" />

Comment: yes. I've those lines. Right now, I'm rerunning the gwt:run-codeserver step everytime for the changes to reflect. Simple "Compile" is just recompiling old code.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw `devModeRedirectEnabled` is not needed in 2.6.1 (and `xsiframe` is the default in 2.7 BTW)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you list `src/main/java` as a `<resource>`, its files are copied to the `${project.build.outputDirectory}`, and that one comes first in the classpath because you could filter files from `<resource>` and have `<source>` and `<resource>` intersect (which is the case here). See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-290

So either:

- remove `src/main/java` from project resources
- remove `*.java` files from project resources (so at least they're not copied over to the output directory and don't shadow `src/main/java`)
- or run `mvn resources:resources` each time you change files in `src/main/java` (like you have to do with files in `src/main/resources`, because of possible filtering); this can be automated by your IDE or some other tool (e.g. [watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/)) though.

Comment: Changes are reflected after modified POM with this segment       <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>

Answer (score 2):

I would upgrade the project to use gwt-2.7.0 and gwt-maven-2.7.0, then nothing special is needed to run superdev mode among your app in a servlet container, just run `mvn gwt:run` and point your browser to `http://localhost:8888`, then each time you change your code just hit refresh in your browser to recompile the app.

As you can see it's pretty simpler, and you would take advance of recompiling in 2.7.0 is a lot faster.

Comment: As you said i upgraded to 2.7.0, and I'm getting  `[INFO]       skipped compile because no input files have changed
[INFO]       1.524s total -- Compile completed` when i change a client source

Comment: are those files in your client package, I mean in the source patch defined in your module.gwt.xml? superdev mode only recompiles changes in gwt src folders inherited in your module

Comment: Yes, these files are in the client package. For some reason, they're not visible to the compiler. If I copy the edited file manually from src/main/java/<package>/client/ to target/<project-name>/WEB-INF/classes/<package>/client/, and reload the web page, i can see the changes

Comment: I'm think your pom is not well configured, maybe the classpath. Can you compare your pom with the generated by webAppCreator -templates maven?

Answer (score 1):

Having tried all possible forums' advice and diverse codeServer launch parameters unsuccessfully, the only means I have found to trigger a refresh without restarting any server is to click again on the bookmark 'Dev Mode Off' followed by 'Dev Mode On' then 'Compile'button ... and the code Server recompiles the changed java source incrementally! (the Dev Mode shortcuts are those you should have dragged from the code server home page like http://localhost:9876 into the browser bookmarks).

A page refresh was enough with "Google Plugin for Eclipse" ( ==GPE, deprecated Jan2018) and -as it seems- no longer with "GWT Eclipse Plugin" (replacing GPE) (appreciate the subtle difference in wordings!)